# Ubuntu server VM problems loading iptable rules on start up

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, ubuntu-server

First of all, once I am logged in I can load the rules manually just fine, by typing

```
sudo iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.new
```

And the rule then appears on

```
sudo iptables -L
```

But I can't make it load automatically no matter what. In /etc/network/interfaces I have this:

```
auto eth0 inet dhcp
adress 192.168.56.101
netmask 255.255.255.0
pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.new
```

Rules in iptables.new are:

```
Generated By iptables-save v1.4.12 on Sun Jul 7 15:28:14 2013
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [4:824]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Jul 7 7 15:28:14 2013
```

Comment: It turns out my iptables are not loaded on boot, because the ufw firewall doesn't isn't start during it. How can I make sure it starts on boot?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Ubuntu system administration. Try [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I usually do is this:

- sudo nano /etc/c.local
- Add "iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.sav" at the end of the file, just BEFORE the "exit 0"

Comment: the file doesn't exist. I am running Ubuntu Server 12.04 32bit. Never mind, I realized you meant rc.local

Comment: whoa, I had spent whole day yesterday trying all sorts of diferent thing without any luck, but this appears to have solved the problems. Thanks!